# web2py redirect to a incorrect page

Tags: html, forms, redirect, web2py

I am learning web2py. I found a redirect error between 2 very simple actions.
This application which I simple modify from the web2py manual is just used to help me to understand the controlflow,request.args and request.vars of web2py. 
Here is the code in my default controller,

```
def index():
    redirect(URL("first",args=1))
def first():
    return dict()
def second():
    return dict()
```

Then I create the first.html and second.html

first.html is

> ```
> <h1>What is your name?</h1>
> <form action="second">
>  <input name="visitor_name" />
>  <input type="submit" />
> </form>
> ```

second.html is

> ```
> <h1>Hello {{=request.vars.visitor_name}}</h1>
> ```

I input something to the form in the first.html,but when I press the submit button it doesn't redirect to the "second" action. And I found something wrong in the url of the browser

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/welcome/default/first/second?visitor_name=zhangsan

I am very confused and do many test. I change the code in the index

from

```
def index():
    redirect(URL("first",args=1))
```

to

```
def index():
    redirect(URL("first"))
```

And the redirect make sense. I am vary confused about this. Is this a bug in web2py or I misunderstand the controlflow of web2py?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The book is incorrect (though the source has now been fixed on Github). In `<form action="second">`, because "second" is not preceded by a "/", the browser interprets it as being relative to the URL of the current page, so it gets appended to the current URL (which is why the form gets submitted to /default/first/second).

Instead, use the `URL()` helper to generate the proper URL:

```
<form action="{{=URL('default', 'second')}}">
```

which will result in the following HTML:

```
<form action="/welcome/default/second">
```

In general, it is always best to use the `URL()` helper to generate internal URLs (particularly if you are using the URL rewrite system, as it will automatically translate the URL based on the rewrite rules).

Comment: Cool, it works. I have totally understood the controlflow and URL helper. It's really very kind of you. Thank you very much, Anthony